# Newline in Telnet server

Tags: ruby, telnet

I am writing a telnet server in Ruby.

The problem I am now facing is that everything is printed on the same line on the client side and `\r\n` isn't working. Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I could do?

Comment: A code snippet reproducing the problem would really be useful for answering this question.

Comment: Not sure, but in PHP if carriage return is in single quotes it won't get transliterated.

Comment: @dbyrne Yeah sorry about that... I came to that realization just a minute ago.. I will edit the post now

Comment: @Chuck Morris - I see.. It's worth a try i guess.

Comment: @Chuck Morris If you post your solution as a "post" i will approve it as the answer. It worked sweetly! Thanks to both of you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but in PHP if carriage return is in single quotes it won't get transliterated.

Happy coding :)